# c# Clear Bitmap from memory

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to: capture the screen, iterate over its pixels and show a message box if a pixel containing the colors specified is detected.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public class API
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr BitBlt(IntPtr hDestDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
    }

    internal class ScreenShot
    {
        public static Bitmap Take()
        {
            int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

            Bitmap screenBmp = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp);

            IntPtr dc1 = API.GetDC(API.GetDesktopWindow());
            IntPtr dc2 = g.GetHdc();

            API.BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);

            // Clean up
            API.ReleaseDC(API.GetDesktopWindow(), dc1);
            g.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
            g.Dispose();

            return screenBmp;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void DoIt()
        {
            Bitmap bmp = ScreenShot.Take();

            // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            // Get the address of the first line.
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
            byte[] r = new byte[bytes / 3];
            byte[] g = new byte[bytes / 3];
            byte[] b = new byte[bytes / 3];

            // Copy the RGB values into the array.
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

            int count = 0;
            int stride = bmpData.Stride;

            for (int column = 0; column < bmpData.Height; column++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < bmpData.Width; row++)
                {
                    int B = (rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3)]);
                    int G = (rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3) + 1]);
                    int R = (rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3) + 2]);

                    if (R == 216 && G == 42 && B == 34)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                    // MessageBox.Show(R.ToString() + "," + G.ToString() + "," + B.ToString());

                    /* b[count] = (byte)(rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3)]);
                    g[count] = (byte)(rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3) + 1]);
                    r[count++] = (byte)(rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3) + 2]); */
                }
            }

            bmp.Dispose();

            if(count >= 1) MessageBox.Show("Found it " + count.ToString() + " times");
        }
    }
}
```

And I call MyClass() like this:

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    MyClass.DoIt();
                }
            });
```

However, the app quickly goes to approx. 2 gb of memory and more. This is basically a memory leak because the bitmap used at each time isn't "freed". How can I solve this?

Comment: You really should be using `SafeHandles` wrapping the IntPtrs  and using `using` blocks. In the event of an exception you are leaking unmanaged resources.

Comment: The arrays are managed, so the garbage collector will clean them up, and the unmanaged resources of the bitmap are disposed. What's the problem, exactly?  The GC will do its work when it feels it is necessary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain could you provide an answer using `SafeHandles ` please?

Comment: @EricLippert when I run the program,it is using a looot of RAM (and like 17% of cpu, but that's probably normal) and it's constantly increasing. This is a problem, the app shouldn't use 2gb of ram and more for just checking pixels on screen

Comment: This is one of very rare cases where it may is acceptable to call *GC.Collect()* followed by a *GC.WaitForPendingFInalizers()*, but **i dont recommend it**. You dont have a mermory leak, you just dont know when the memory is going to be freed, this is not an issue at all, the framework takes care of this. Anyways you should use usings to ensure that all object are beeing disposed properly even if an exception occurs.

Comment: First, who says it's using RAM? It's surely using *memory*, but who says that memory is RAM?  Memory hasn't been RAM in decades; memory is *page file*, and RAM makes your page file access faster when the working set is sufficiently small.  Probably you are measuring reserved address space, not RAM.

Comment: Second, apparently it *does* take 2GB of address space to read pixels on the screen. Who cares? A 64 bit application has way more address space than that to spare.  **You still haven't said what the real problem is**. Let the garbage collector do its work.

Comment: Just a simple bug, you forgot to call UnlockBits().

Comment: @EricLippert what I see is more than 2000 MB of memory usage in the task manager. It _ really matters_: what if I'm using this app while running another resource-intensive app? Anyway, it shouldn't be using that much memory for _just_ checking for pixels in screen

Comment: @HansPassant oh, thanks! now it's only using 40 mb of memory `;)`

Comment: @HansPassant: That is surprising!  I would have expected disposing a bitmap to automatically unlock it. Were I still at Coverity, I'd be writing a checker to check for that one like, *right now*.

Comment: OMG it gets worse. The Windows API documentation for LockBits says that UnlockBits *updates the bitmap*. The documentation for UnlockBits says that a locked bitmap is *required* to be unlocked.  Those are two very different things!